# Access tuples data that is inside a list

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

If I want to access/references a character parameter in my function I just do like this:

```
myFunc :: Char -> Bool
myFunc c = ... --Here I use 'c' to work with my Char parameter
```

Working with lists:

```
myList :: [Int] -> [Int]
myList l = ... --I can access the list with 'l'.
```

Now, how may I access/work/references the tuple data when it's inside a list:

```
myFunc :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)] --Receive a list of tuple as parameter
myFunc ?? = ... --How may I access the tuple element ? How may I access its data. Just use a letter there and try to work with `fst` or `snd` does not work.
```

*Update*

```
myFunc :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]
myFunc  [] = [(0, 0)]
myFunc ((x,y):rest) = x --Error here:  
Couldn't match expected type `[(Int, Int)]' with actual type `Int' In the  expression: x
```

Comment: You are getting the error because `x` is a value of type `Int`. Your type signature indicates that your function is returning value of type `[(Int, Int)]` but you are actually returning `Int` and hence the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually asking how to do pattern matching. This is the general way of doing this in your case:

```
myFunc :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]
myFunc [] = undefined
myFunc ((x,y):[]) = undefined
myFunc ((x,y):rest) = undefined
```

The pattern `((x,y):[])` will match list with only one element. The `x` refers to the first element in the tuple and `y` the second element. Similarly, in the pattern `((x,y):rest)`, `rest` refers to the rest of the list apart from the first (or the head) element.

Another similar but less powerful way of doing the same would be like this:

```
myFunc :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]
myFunc [] = undefined
myFunc (first:[]) = undefined
myFunc (first:rest) = undefined
```

Here in the pattern `(first:rest)` the head element of the list is referenced by the variable `first`. Now to access the tuples inside it, you can use the `fst` and the `snd` combinator.

Comment: I tried: `myFunc ((x,y):rest)` but I got this error: `Couldn't match expected type [(Int, Int)] with actual type Int In the expression: x `

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Can you post your full code which you have tried ?

Comment: You rock man ! One last thing. Let's say I want to add +1 for every value, I now how to do it with high ordern function but I want to do it recursively. How may I call the function again and skip to the next tuple ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Some hints: You increment the tuple initially like `(x + 1, y + 1)` and then pass the `rest` parameter to itself recursively. Glue them with the list constructor function `:` and your function is almost ready.